# How to check same set of permissions assigned to another role?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using `spatie permission package` in Laravel and I want to make sure that two roles with different names must not have same permissions while creating a role e.g

```
Role A
 - Pemission 1
 - Permission 2
 - Permission 3

Role B
 - Pemission 1
 - Permission 2
 - Permission 3
```

If this happens system should not create 2nd role "Role B"

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you’ve published the configuration file(`config/permissions.php`) of the package. If not, run

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider"`

2. Extend the `Spatie\Permission\Models\Role` model.
3. Change the configuration file to point the extended role model instead of the default one.
4. Override the static `boot` method inside the extended model and add this callback:

```
self::creatig(function($model) {
    $permissions = $model->permissions;
    $existingRoles = Role::whereHas('permissions', function($query) using $permissions {
        $query->whereIn('id', $permissions->pluck('id'));
    })->get();
    if (!$existingPosts->isEmpty()) throw Exception('There is already a role with these permissions');
});
```

5. You can catch this exception later in the controller and return the error message as a response if you want to let the user know what happened.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution thank you for helping

```
 $roles = Role::get();
        $permissions = $request->input('permissions');
        $notSame = false;
        $sameRole = null;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($roles); $i++) {
            $role_permissions[$i] = $roles[$i]->getAllPermissions()
                ->pluck('id')->toArray();
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($role_permissions[$i]); $j++) {
                if ($role_permissions[$i] == $permissions) {
                    $notSame = true;
                    $sameRole = $roles[$i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        /**
         * Below condition will check if same set of permissions is
         * not assigned to any other role then It will be processed
         * further otherwise user have to choose different set of
         * permission
         *
         */
        if ($notSame && ($sameRole != null)) {
            alert()->warning('Role Already Exists', 'A role named as "' . $sameRole->name . '" with same permissions 
             already exists try with another permissions set');
         return redirect()->back();

        } else {

    - Write here your code to store into DB
    }
```